# Redux, updating array in state breaks stuff

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sockets, redux, socket.io

I have a connection to the backend through `socket.io`. I can send messages and recieve callback successfully and it works fine for a while. The first 12 messages are sent correctly, I recieve callback and update my `Redux` state. But when I send 13th message my socket gets reinitiated instead of emitting *'sendMessage'* signal. Socket gets a new id and connects to the backend. It almost always happens exactly on the 13th try of emitting this signal. Other signals work fine and won't reinitiate the socket even if I repeat them more than 12 times.

socketActions.ts file

```
import { Channel, Message, SocketCallback, User } from "../types";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5000/";
const socket = io(ENDPOINT);

export const sendMessage = (msg: string, author: User, channel: Channel, 
  callback: (res: SocketCallback) => void
) => {
  const data: Message = { msg, author, channel };
  socket.emit("sendMessage", data, (res: SocketCallback) => {
    callback(res);
  });
};
```

SendMessage.tsx component in which I trigger this function.

```
const send = () => {
  const author: User = {
    name: user.displayName,
    email: user.email,
    avatar: user.photoURL,
  };
  if (message) {
    sendMessage(message, author, channel, (res: SocketCallback) => {
      dispatch(channelMessagesAdd(res.data));
      const body = document.querySelector(".chatMessages");
      if (body) body.scrollTop = body.scrollHeight;
    });
    setMessage("");
  }
};
```

This is the channelMessagesAdd redux action

```
export const channelMessagesAdd = (status: Message) => {
  return {
    type: "CHANNEL_MESSAGE_ADD",
    payload: status,
  };
};
```

And Redux state in which I add messages to a channel.

```
case "CHANNEL_MESSAGE_ADD":
  return state.map((channel: Channel) => {
    const msg: Message = action.payload as Message;
    if (channel.id !== msg.channel.id) return channel;
    else return { ...channel, messages: [...channel.messages, msg] };
  });
```

When I edited the last file and did something like this

> else return { ...channel, messages: ['test'] };

it would work as intended, so my guess is that `messages: [...channel.messages, msg]` somehow breaks stuff. Any idea why?

Comment: Try reversing the condition: `if (String(channel.id) === String(msg.channel.id)) return modified state`. Also, inside this `if` block, check `channel.messages` and `msg` values by printing these on console log.

Comment: Reversing the statement didn't help. Everything looks fine in the redux state, messages are added as intended and all data is correct. When I call send() for the 13th time from SendMessage.tsx component, it executes function from socketActions.ts file, but instead of emitting signal, socket reconnects to the backend, and gets new id and it never calls callback with the desired data.